# Fill in a row based on a drop-down list

Tags: google-sheets

I created in sheet 2 a list of names (column A1:A20). Each name, on the next 10 columns has different information (B1:B20, C1:C20 and so on).

In sheet 1 I created a drop-down list (with data validation) for the names in sheet 2 (A1:A20) and whenever I choose a value from the drop down list, I want to have all the corresponding information  (from sheet 2) copied on that row in sheet 1.

Is there a way to use a formula for this? Or if VBA is the way, can someone direct me to how to achieve this. Please consider I have zero to nothing experience with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILTER()` or `QUERY()` formula. Try-

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!B1:K3,Sheet2!A1:A3=A1)
```

Comment: It is not working exactly like I want but I think I can work on it to properly adapt it. thanks